# Unresolved reference for all builtin methods with red underline

Tags: android, kotlin

In android studio wherever i am using builtin  methods of kotlin such as `apply(),let() ,contentEquals()` etc,  getting underline error message as Unresolved reference: with method name.tried with build clean project, invalidate cache/restart still same issue, but project building is successful and able to install apk
Using android studio 3.2.1 , Kotlin 1.2.71,kotlin plugin Version: 1.2.71-release-Studio3.2-1.
[image]

Comment: Could you please add more details/ screenshots of the issue?

Comment: @Quantum_VC added screenshot

Comment: Please make sure that you have a dependency on `kotlin-stdlib` in your build.gradle.

Comment: @yole yes its there implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71'
and able to build apk   successfully.

Comment: Try running gradle sync again?

Comment: gradle sync,clean,rebuild nothing helped to resolve issue..

Comment: @yole any furthermore information needed from my side?.

Comment: What happens if you press Goto Symbol and enter "apply"?

Comment: showing message like:  can't find declaration to go to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182073/discussion-between-ask-and-yole).

Comment: Try Invalidate cache and Restart

Comment: @Tsuharesu after trying  Invalidate cache and Restart i posted above issue..